# In Android compound view is not accepting onclick from xml

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-databinding

I've developed a custom compound view which has a `Button` and a `ProgressBar` in it. I'm using `databinding` in my app. Compound view is not accepting `onClick` event, how to sort this issue?

```
<com.ui.custom.LoadingButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/bg_color"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.onNextClick()}"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:isLoading="@{viewModel.isLoading}" />
```

**Layout of Loading Button:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text_size" />

        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_loading_indicator"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_loading_indicator"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
            app:indicatorName="LineSpinFadeLoaderIndicator" />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Or If I use 'onClick' attribute of android, then how can i get it in TypedArray? So i can set it to view programmatically.

```
   <declare-styleable name="LoadingButton">
        <attr name="isLoading" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="android:text" />
        <attr name="android:textColor" />
        <attr name="android:background" />
        <attr name="android:onClick" />

    </declare-styleable>
```

LoadingButton java

```
@BindingMethods({
        @BindingMethod(type = LoadingButton.class, attribute = "onLoadingButtonClick", method = "onLoadingButtonClick"),
})
public class LoadingButton extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private int background, textColor;
    private boolean isLoading;
    private String btnText;
    private LayoutLoadingBtnBinding itemViewBinding;
    private OnLoadingButtonListener listener;

    public LoadingButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializeView(context, null, 0);
    }

    public LoadingButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initializeView(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public LoadingButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initializeView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void initializeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        mContext = context;
        TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LoadingButton, defStyleAttr, 0);

        try {
            background = array.getColor(R.styleable.LoadingButton_android_background, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            textColor = array.getColor(R.styleable.LoadingButton_android_textColor, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            btnText = array.getString(R.styleable.LoadingButton_android_text);
            isLoading = array.getBoolean(R.styleable.LoadingButton_isLoading, false);
            //   Method onClick = array.getValue(R.styleable.LoadingButton_android_onClick);
        } finally {
            array.recycle();
        }

        itemViewBinding = LayoutLoadingBtnBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(mContext), this, true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

      //  setOnClickListener(this::onClick);
        setValues();

    }

    private void setValues() {
        try {
            if (background != Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                itemViewBinding.parentFrame.setBackgroundColor(background);

            if (background != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                itemViewBinding.button.setTextColor(textColor);
                itemViewBinding.loadingIndicator.setIndicatorColor(textColor);
            }
            itemViewBinding.button.setText(btnText);
            updateLoadingViews();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void updateLoadingViews() {
        itemViewBinding.button.setVisibility(isLoading ? INVISIBLE : VISIBLE);
        itemViewBinding.loadingIndicator.setVisibility(isLoading ? VISIBLE : GONE);
    }

    public void setLoading(boolean isLoading) {
        if (this.isLoading != isLoading)  // update only if loading state is changed
        {
            this.isLoading = isLoading;
            updateLoadingViews();
        }
    }

    public void setOnLoadingButtonClick(OnLoadingButtonListener listener) {
        AppLogger.d("usm_loading_btn_0", "setOnLoadingButtonClick is called: listener= " + (listener != null));
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        AppLogger.d("usm_loading_btn_1", "onClick is called");
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onLoadingButtonClick();
        }
    }

    public interface OnLoadingButtonListener {
        void onLoadingButtonClick();
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried using button id to implement onClick listener ?

Comment: The parent itself is LinearLayout, i want to implement onClick on that instead of its child or on child without accessing ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not using this way

```
<attr name="android:onClick" />
```

Try to using `BindingMethods`

```
@BindingMethods({
        @BindingMethod(type = LoadingButton.class, attribute = "onLoadingButtonClick", method = "onLoadingButtonClick"),
})
public class LoadingButton extends YOUR_ROOT_VIEW implements View.OnClickListener {
  // your item view class.
  private OnLoadingButtonListener listener;

  public void setOnLoadingButtonClick(OnLoadingButtonListener listener) {
     this.listener = listener;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onLoadingButtonClick();
    }
  }
  public interface OnLoadingButtonListener {
    void onLoadingButtonClick();
  }
}
```

and in your layout

```
<com.ui.custom.LoadingButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/bg_color"
            android:onLoadingButtonClick="@{()->viewModel.onNextClick()}"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:isLoading="@{viewModel.isLoading}" />
```

**UPDATE 1**

If your `onClick()` not working, remove it and try to using this way

```
private void initializeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        mContext = context;
        TypedArray array =
                context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LoadingButton, defStyleAttr, 0);

        try {
            background =
                    array.getColor(R.styleable.LoadingButton_android_background, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            textColor =
                    array.getColor(R.styleable.LoadingButton_android_textColor, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            btnText = array.getString(R.styleable.LoadingButton_android_text);
            isLoading = array.getBoolean(R.styleable.LoadingButton_isLoading, false);
            //   Method onClick = array.getValue(R.styleable.LoadingButton_android_onClick);
        } finally {
            array.recycle();
        }

        itemViewBinding =
                LayoutLoadingBtnBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(mContext), this, true);
        itemViewBinding.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onLoadingButtonClick();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution. But my onClick is not calling , though 'setOnLoadingButtonClick' is caling fine

Comment: still same ... onClick is not calling

Comment: try again with `itemViewBinding.button`, see my update answer

Comment: It is working on button click, can we make it work on parent view?

Comment: I think because you using button with match parent layout, so the parent view can not get the click listener

Comment: point, so it should work if we disable child views click. 
And how can we do it without databinding?

Comment: yes, you can using `LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_btn, this, true);` to inflate your layout

Comment: I mean, the onClick thing

Comment: Can you please check this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096414/textinputlayout-is-not-showing-expanded-hint-in-custom-compound-view